# Functional Dependencies and Primary Keys

Tags: relational-database, primary-key, functional-dependencies

**Question**

Does a Primary Key functionally determine every other attribute in the table?

**My thought**

Surely it has to doesn't it? Isn't that the point of primary keys?

Comment: Re "the point of primary keys", see my answer & its link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a table that is at least in 1st normal form, the primary key determines every attribute *in the table*.  As you say, that is the point of primary keys (and candidate keys in general).

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi Normal forms describe relations, and as philipxy explained, primary keys play no role in relational theory. To clarify my point, in a table that has a primary key and represents a relation (which is equivalent to being in at least 1NF), that primary key will necessarily functionally determine every attribute in the table. In a table that does not represent a relation, we can't necessarily make such guarantees. As other respondents pointed out, in any relation, all superkeys will determine all attributes of the relation.

Answer (score 5):

There is by definition a functional dependency between *all* superkeys (not just the primary key) of a relation and *all* attributes in that relation (not just non-key attributes).

Answer (score 5):

A table's *superkeys* (UNIQUE NOT NULL sets of columns) are the column sets that "functionally determine every other attribute in the table". A table's *candidate keys* (superkeys containing no smaller superkeys) are important to normalization.  A *primary key* is just a distinguished candidate key.

*Why* distinguish one?

- Primary keys play no role in relational theory. The main practical role is for consistency in identifying rows/entities/associations by foreign keys in other tables.
- Codd (contrary to theory) allowed NULL in candidate key columns. (As does SQL.) From his ["Understanding Relations"](http://www.sigmod.org/sigmod-history/7-1975) articles:

  > A basic integrity principle associated with candidate keys
  >   is that, for every base relation, at least one of the
  >   candidate keys is prohibited from taking on null values.

  > Normally, it will not be necessary to prohibit null values
  >   in more than one candidate key -- hence, the common practice
  >   of designating precisely one such key as the primary key:
  >   i.e., the only candidate key for which null values are
  >   prohibited.
- (DBMSs, CASE tools and ORMs often use primary keys for defaults associated with candidate keys, often physical/implementation ones. But this [begs the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9509661/3404097).)

So superkeys play the identification role, candidate keys are the special superkeys, and primary keys aren't particularly special candidate keys.